# Applying quantifier to a sentence in Lua pattern

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns, luajit

So I am trying to parse out `#define` statements out of a C file using Lua patterns, but there is the case on multiline defines, where you might escape the newline character with a backslash.

In order for me to know where the define ends, I need to be able to define `backslash + linebreak` as if it were a single character so I can get the complement of that and then use the `*` quantifier on it and then count until the first non-escaped linebreak.

How do I do that?

Comment: You cannot quantify sequences with Lua patterns. However, you can work around it by first replacing the sequence with some temp value, run the collect the matches you need, and post-process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply replace all occurrences of  `"\\\n"` with some temporary symbol, because a problem will arise with the line `"c\\\\\n"` in the following example.
Instead, you should implement mini-scanner for C source files:

```
local str = [[
#define x y
#define a b\
c\\
d();
#define z
]]

-- Print all #defines found in the text
local line = ""
for char in str:gmatch"\\?." do
   if char == "\n" then
      if line:sub(1, #"#define") == "#define" then
         print(line)
      end
      line = ""
   else
      line = line..char
   end
end
```

Output:

```
#define x y
#define a b\
c\\
#define z
```